# Finding minimum value for each row from 2 matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I need the minimum value for each rows from 2 matrix. The row names are common in both matrix but the column name changes.

eg:

```
matrix 1:
X <- matrix(runif(20), nrow=4)
rownames(X) <- paste0("Inst", seq(nrow(X)))
colnames(X) <- paste0("Ref", seq(ncol(X)))

matrix 2:
Y <- matrix(runif(20), nrow=4)
rownames(Y) <- paste0("Inst", seq(nrow(X)))
colnames(Y) <- paste0("Alt", seq(ncol(X)))
```

Expected result:

```
             Minimum    Id
    Inst1   0.1275317  Ref15
    Inst2   0.0006247  Alt4
    Inst3   0.04583117 Ref13
    Inst4   0.1111354  Alt5
```

I tried

```
t(apply(Y, 1, sort)[ 1, ]) 
t(apply(X, 1, sort)[ 1, ])
```

Yet don't know how to find the minimum from both matrix and tabulate separately as expected output file. Also I have duplicated rownames and colnames.

Comment: Please always use a fixed seed (e.g. `set.seed(1234)`) to ensure reproducibility of your expected output when using sample data based on random numbers. Otherwise there is no way to reproduce your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` possibility. Note that I've used the fixed seed `set.seed(2017)` for the generation of sample data.

```
library(tidyverse)
cbind.data.frame(X, Y) %>%
    rownames_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(Id, Minimum, -row) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    filter(Minimum == min(Minimum)) %>%
    arrange(row)
## A tibble: 4 x 3
## Groups:   row [4]
#  row   Id    Minimum
#  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#1 Inst1 Ref4  0.0251
#2 Inst2 Alt5  0.110
#3 Inst3 Ref2  0.0393
#4 Inst4 Ref3  0.00202
```

---

### Sample data

```
set.seed(2017)
X <- matrix(runif(20), nrow=4)
rownames(X) <- paste0("Inst", seq(nrow(X)))
colnames(X) <- paste0("Ref", seq(ncol(X)))

Y <- matrix(runif(20), nrow=4)
rownames(Y) <- paste0("Inst", seq(nrow(Y)))
colnames(Y) <- paste0("Alt", seq(ncol(Y)))
```

---

### Update

In response to your comment, to retain the top 3 lowest entries you can use `top_n` (as suggested by @Moody_Mudskipper)

```
cbind.data.frame(X, Y) %>%
    rownames_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(Id, Minimum, -row) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    top_n(-3, Minimum) %>%
    arrange(row, Minimum)
## A tibble: 12 x 3
## Groups:   row [4]
#   row   Id    Minimum
#   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 Inst1 Ref4  0.0251
# 2 Inst1 Alt3  0.0763
# 3 Inst1 Alt5  0.129
# 4 Inst2 Alt5  0.110
# 5 Inst2 Alt4  0.212
# 6 Inst2 Alt3  0.261
# 7 Inst3 Ref2  0.0393
# 8 Inst3 Alt5  0.177
# 9 Inst3 Ref1  0.469
#10 Inst4 Ref3  0.00202
#11 Inst4 Alt3  0.0175
#12 Inst4 Ref1  0.289
```

Comment: Hi Maurits, Thanks! I have duplicated rownames and colnames, but I don't want to make unique list. How to keep duplicated rownames and colnames and still achieve this output?

Comment: @amarPar I'm not sure what you mean. Please update your post to include a more representative sample dataset plus expected output (remember to use a fixed seed).

Comment: you can also use `top_n(-1,"Minimum")` instead of your `filter ` call

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper That's neat; I never realised `top_n` can take a third argument. Thanks for the that:-)

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to keep the results for 1st, 2nd and 3rd minimum values as well. I would prefer to keep all if 2 or more different Ids get same values and satisfy the 1st, 2nd or 3rd minimum criteria. Thanks.

Comment: @amarPar I've updated my post in response to your comment. Please take a look.

Comment: @Maurits Evers Thanks for the quick update. 1) I have some common Ids between these 2 matrix.  I get Inst1 Alt3  0.0763, Inst1 Alt3.1  0.124 etc , how to keep only one of them. 2) I want unique Ids while calculating minimum, for example, if Inst1 picked Alt5 as minimum, the next row (Inst2) should not pick the same(even if the minimum is for Alt5 again). Hence, I should skip if they have been chosen before as minimum and look for the next minimum and report them. Could you help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: @amarPar These go way beyond your original question. Please post a new question with representative sample data, your code attempt and your expected output.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I made a new post for unique minimum. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819356/unique-minimum-for-each-rows-from-2-matrix-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your matrix with `cbind` and transpose it with `t()`.  Then a `summarise_all` from `dplyr` could give you a min for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(t(cbind(X,Y))) %>% summarise_all(funs(min))
#        Inst1       Inst2       Inst3      Inst4
# 1 0.05845904 0.006901952 0.009513836 0.05197972
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sample data from @Maurits, in base R :

```
XY <- cbind(X,Y)
wm_     <- apply(XY,1,which.min)
Minimum <- apply(XY,1,min)
data.frame(Minimum, id = colnames(XY)[wm_])
#           Minimum   id
# Inst1 0.025093514 Ref4
# Inst2 0.110404957 Alt5
# Inst3 0.039322336 Ref2
# Inst4 0.002020766 Ref3
```

Comment: Hi Moody, Thanks, I got error, data.frame(Minimum, id = colnames(XY)[wm_])
Error in data.frame(Minimum, id = colnames(XY)[wm_]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 4.

Comment: With your real data, not the data from the sample, right ?

Comment: this is really odd, these are really simple and stable functions and it works fine on my side, please double check that you copied it well from @Maurits' post and that you didn't overwrite `Minimum` or `wm_`, then if it still fails tell me what are `length(Minimum)` and `length(colnames(XY)[wm_]))`

Comment: Yes, I copied right from Maurit'´s post. > length(Minimum)
[1] 40
> length(colnames(XY)[wm_])
[1] 4