# unique minimum for each rows from 2 matrix R

Tags: r

I have 2 matrix with same rownames and I found the first 3 minimum value for each rows (thanks to @ Maurits Evers). Now I need to find the 3 minimum value but without repeated colnames. I want unique Ids while calculating minimum, for example, if Inst1 picked Alt5 as minimum, the next row (Inst2) should not pick the same. Hence, I should skip if they have been chosen before as minimum and look for the next minimum and report them. But if the 2nd row with minimum is lower than 1st rows minimums then the 1st row will be replaced with the next minimim value of that particular row. Any suggestions?

```
set.seed(2017)
X <- matrix(runif(20), nrow=4)
rownames(X) <- paste0("Inst", seq(nrow(X)))
colnames(X) <- paste0("Ref", seq(ncol(X)))

Y <- matrix(runif(20), nrow=4)
rownames(Y) <- paste0("Inst", seq(nrow(Y)))
colnames(Y) <- paste0("Alt", seq(ncol(Y)))

cbind.data.frame(X, Y) %>%
    rownames_to_column("row") %>%
    gather(Id, Minimum, -row) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    top_n(-3, Minimum) %>%
    arrange(row, Minimum)

## A tibble: 12 x 3
## Groups:   row [4]
#   row   Id    Minimum
#   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 Inst1 Ref4  0.0251
# 2 Inst1 Alt3  0.0763
# 3 Inst1 Alt5  0.129
# 4 Inst2 Alt5  0.110
# 5 Inst2 Alt4  0.212
# 6 Inst2 Alt3  0.261
# 7 Inst3 Ref2  0.0393
# 8 Inst3 Alt5  0.177
# 9 Inst3 Ref1  0.469
#10 Inst4 Ref3  0.00202
#11 Inst4 Alt3  0.0175
#12 Inst4 Ref1  0.289

#Expected output:
 Inst Min1 1 Min2 2 Min3 3
 Inst1 Ref4  0.0251 Alt2  0.228 Ref5 0.395375 
 Inst2 Alt5  0.110 Alt4  0.212 Alt1 0.380 
 Inst4 Ref3  0.00202 Alt3  0.0175 Ref1  0.289
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for question and comments. A bit strait forward solution: to have a loop with selecting minimum which is not in previous and recording previously selected Minimums to define which is the minimum for given ID. For formating spread function could be used

```
      mindata <-as.data.frame(cbind.data.frame(X, Y) %>%
      rownames_to_column("row") %>%
      gather(Id, Minimum, -row) %>%
      arrange(row, Minimum))

Pr_min <- c()
Def_min <- c()
par<-sum(mindata$row=="Inst1")
i<-1

  for (row in unique(mindata$row)){
    initial3 <- head(mindata[mindata$row==row & !(mindata$Id %in% Pr_min$Id), c(1:3) ], 3)
   if(nrow(initial3)==0){next} 
    New_min <-mindata[(1 +(i-1)*par):max(rownames(initial3)), 2:3]

    Pr_min <- rbind(Pr_min, initial3)
    Def_min <- rbind(Def_min, New_min)
    i <- i+1
  }

  Final <- Pr_min %>%
  left_join((Def_min%>%
  group_by(Id)%>%
  summarise(min=min(Minimum))), by="Id")%>%
  select(-Minimum)

CN <- rep(c("Min1", "Min2", "Min3"), ceiling(length(Final$Id)/3))[1:nrow(Final)]
Val_min <-Final%>% cbind( CN) %>% select(-Id)%>% spread(CN, min)
name_min <-Final%>% cbind( CN ) %>% select(-min)%>% spread(CN, Id)
cbind(name_min,Val_min[, 2:4])
```

Comment: @ Nar, thanks for changing the ouput layout. I need the Min1, Min2, Min3 to be unique with minimums.

Comment: @ Nar, I got an error with slightly bigger matrix, eg `X <- matrix(runif(100), nrow=10),  Y <- matrix(runif(100), nrow=10)` as input `Error in (1 + (i - 1) * 10):max(rownames(initial3)) : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In max(rownames(initial3)) : no non-missing arguments, returning NA`

Comment: You have only 20 unique ID that means tat only 7 Inst are shown with unique Id. PS also in case of size change need to introduce parameter: number of rows for each row . It can be expressed as par<-sum(mindata$row==row). I did change in example to make it more general

Comment: Hi, I don't see the par<-sum(mindata$row==row) changes in the example. Could you please update. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I wanted to change the output layout (as shown in the expected output) and ended up with error Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 18 . Also in the output the min values look different eventhough the Id didn't got changed. 
eg,`mindata
       row    Id      Minimum
1    Inst1  Alt7 0.0047569799
2    Inst1  Ref9 0.1446757889
3    Inst1  Alt2 0.1525822617`

`Final
      row    Id          min
1   Inst1  Alt7 0.0047569799
2   Inst1  Ref9 0.0858710501
3   Inst1  Alt2 0.0482392930`

Comment: for last inst you have only 2 unique minimums since the list was exhausted. Thus have to build names vector equal to size of you final unique minimum selection.  CN <- rep(c("Min1", "Min2", "Min3"), ceiling(length(Final$Id)/3))[1:nrow(Final)]
      
     Val_min <-Final%>%
      cbind( CN) %>%
      select(-Id)%>%
      spread(CN, min)
    
    
    name_min <-Final%>%
      cbind( CN ) %>%
      select(-min)%>%
      spread(CN, Id)
    
    cbind(name_min,Val_min[, 2:4])

Comment: Hi, I noticed that some minimum are not right. eg 1st row (Inst1) `row  Min1 Min2  Min3         Min1       Min2       Min3`
`1  Inst1  Alt7 Ref9  Alt2 0.0047569799 0.08587105 0.04823929` but in mindata, Inst10 Ref9 0.0858710501 and Inst2 Alt2 0.0482392930 . Why these are in Inst1. Also I would expect, `row  Min1 Min2  Min3         Min1       Min2       Min3`
`1  Inst1  Alt7 NA NA 0.0047569799 NA NA` as non of the other Ids got minimum with Inst1 compare to the others.

Comment: in probem statement it is written: "But if the 2nd row with minimum is lower than 1st rows minimums then the 1st row will be replaced with the next minimim value of that particular row". You can modify code if problem statement to be changed